# optimizing a long run time linq Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

i have this linq expression in my mv3-entity project

```
    SubCatNews = (from c in context.NewsInSubCats
      where
      (c.SubCat.Visible == true &&
          c.SubCatNews.Visible == true &&
          c.SubCatNews.StatusID == 1 &&
          c.SubCatNews.NewsTypeID != 5 &&
          (c.SubCatID == catId || c.SubCat.ParentId == catId))
orderby c.SubCatNews.SubCatNewsID descending
      select c.SubCatNews)
.Distinct()
.OrderByDescending(p => p.SubCatNewsID)
.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize);
```

i have amount 23000 record in SubCatNews table(my News)

these records,use NewsInSubCats table for assocating groups to News

and groups are in SubCat table

this worked,but fetch proccess from sql server have long time execute and return Timeout Exeption from sql server in most time

i hosted 3 site with this structure in a virtual dedicated server with 2 GB ram

is this Linq expression optimize?

or i have to using indexing in sql server

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest. Create a indexing on sql server and write a store procedure and pass all the required parameters (including pageindex and pagesize) and did filter at SQL side and return required data only.

TO create a store procedure you can check following URL.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/randyp/archive/2005/06/23/6335.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx

http://basquang.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/stored-procedures-paging-solution-in-asp-net-mvc-2/

Comment: i guese this work,i request a cpu core and more memory from my server provider too.  tanx for your reply